# Make docker wordpress:php8.3-apache mysql to use encryption connection connection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to set https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress -> wordpress:php8.3-apache's mysql client to use encryption connection with the MySQL server.

I've defined the MYSQL options in wp-config.php

```
define("MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS", MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL | MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT);
define("DB_SSL", true);
define("MYSQL_SSL_KEY", "/usr/src/wordpress/sql/client-key.pem");
define("MYSQL_SSL_CERT", "/usr/src/wordpress/sql/client-cert.pem");
define("MYSQL_SSL_CA", "/usr/src/wordpress/sql/server-ca.pem");
```

Obviously I also copied these files (*.pem) in the specified directory `/usr/src/wordpress/sql/`

The issue is that I get "access denied" error. I believe the certificates are not being used.

`PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'x.190' (using password: YES) in /usr/src/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line 1987`

Why is this happening? How can I check if it's using the certificates provided and if not why not?

Comment: How is the user created in MySQL? Which MySQL version? Does the MySQL server container the CA key/cert? Why are you using a root user to wordpress?

Comment: the mysql version has nothing to do with this. It's just the pile of junk named PHP & wordpress the issue. MySQL is a managed server on Google Cloud where I created the certificates. Wordpress simply is not able to handle certificates for mysql out of the box. There are 10+ years old issues both on wordpress itself and on PHP.

Comment: related to [wp ticket 28625](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28625)?

Comment: Yes, oepened 10 years ago...

Comment: Since you found an answer, would you like to close, self-answer, or upvote and accept the existing answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a typical s*** php ecosystem gem. There is a [17 years old comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php#126807) on mysqli options documentation that says:

```
Although it is not explained on the manual, 
MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT is an option only valid for mysqlnd
and will raise an error if used with mysqli.
```

This gave me a hint and after several tests I've found out that wordpress is not using mysqlnd for whatever reason. mysqlnd is not installed. Installing it seems an impossible task so I gave up to that. Basically all the certificate constants were defined in vain(i.e. worthless) and wordpress does not support encrypted mysql connections(at least not through configuration).

It looks like the method to use certificates for mysql  is to edit  `/usr/src/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php` and use mysqli_ssl_set:

`mysqli_ssl_set($this->dbh, MYSQL_SSL_KEY, MYSQL_SSL_CERT, MYSQL_SSL_CA,NULL,NULL);` just after mysqli_init()

You can use this line during your build process:
`sed -i -e 's/mysqli_init();/mysqli_init();\nmysqli_ssl_set($this->dbh, MYSQL_SSL_KEY, MYSQL_SSL_CERT, MYSQL_SSL_CA,NULL,NULL);/g' /usr/src/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php`

There is also a [note](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ssl-set.php) that says `Be warned, MySQL prior to versions 5.7.3 do not require the server to use SSL [1]. In the case of PHP the client won't throw an error if the connection is downgraded to plain-text [2]` so take this encryption/security with a grain of salt.

If you have the chance avoid PHP like plague. The entire ecosystem including PHP's own documentation is a big pile of junk.